Triangle-removal lemma-like question
Question
Fix $\delta > 0$. Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices and has at least $n^2/4 + \delta n^2$ edges. We apply the regularity lemma (with a suitable $\epsilon$ and $t \geq 1$ which we can specify later) and obtain an equitable $\epsilon$-regular partition of $G$, say $\mathcal P = \{V_1, \dots, V_k\}$.
Let $R$ be a graph on vertex set $[k]$, where edge $ij$ exists if and only if the pair $(V_i, V_j)$ is $\epsilon$-regular and $d(V_i, V_j) \geq 2 \epsilon$. The '$d$' here stands for density between sets $V_i$ and $V_j$. Show that, for an appropriate $\epsilon$, the graph $R$ has more than $k^2/4$ edges.
Attempt
There are $\binom{k}{2}$ number of pairs $(V_i, V_j)$ total. We need to remove the pairs which are not $\epsilon$-regular or $d(V_i, V_j) < 2 \epsilon$. We remove each in turn.

Since $\mathcal P$ is an $\epsilon$-regular partition, there is at most $\epsilon k^2$ number of pairs $(V_i, V_j)$ which are not $\epsilon$-regular.

Not sure how to count how many pairs are $d(V_i, V_j) < 2 \epsilon$. I was thinking maybe it relates to the number of edges since we know the number of edges between $V_i$ and $V_j$ is $e(V_i, V_j) < 2 \epsilon |V_i| |V_j| \approx 2 \epsilon (n/k)^2$ since $\mathcal P$ is equitable. Then we could maybe relate this to the fact that we need at least $n^2/4 + \delta n^2$ edges, but I am not sure. Suppose for now, we determine there are at most $M=M(\epsilon)$ (some function of $\epsilon)$ number of such pairs.


Then we remove at most $\epsilon k^2 + M(\epsilon)$ number of pairs. So the number of edges in $R$ would be at least $\binom{k}{2} - \epsilon k^2 - M(\epsilon)$. And since we want this number to be greater than $k^2/4$, we then choose a suitable $\epsilon$ such that it works.
Is this correct idea? And in particular, how do we do the counting in the second removal step?
